# Ignite UriDeploymentSpi - Unable to start Ignite server in docker with ignite-urideploy module

Tags: ignite

I try to start the ignite server in the docker and enable module ignite-urideploy.

I followed the config instruction according to [ignite document](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/code-deployment/deploying-user-code)

With the config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="true"/>
    <property name="deploymentMode" value="CONTINUOUS"/>
    <property name="deploymentSpi">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.deployment.uri.UriDeploymentSpi">
            <property name="temporaryDirectoryPath" value="/tmp/temp_ignite_libs"/>
            <property name="uriList">
                <list>
                    <value>file://freq=2000@localhost/opt/ignite/apache-ignite/libs/user_libs</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

Then, I started ignite cluster (server) in docker with command below,

Additional context: I added postgresql jar file because I'm going to use ignite with external persistence (read-through-write-through)

```
docker run -d  \
    -v /{path_to_config}/config.xml:/opt/ignite/apache-ignite/config.xml \
    -v /{path_to_config}/postgresql-42.5.0.jar:/opt/ignite/apache-ignite/libs/user_libs/postgresql-42.5.0.jar \
    -v /{path_to_config}/ignite-temp/ignite-urideploy-2.14.0.jar:/opt/ignite/apache-ignite/libs/ignite-urideploy-2.14.0.jar \
    -e CONFIG_URI=/opt/ignite/apache-ignite/config.xml \
    -e USER_LIBS=/opt/ignite/apache-ignite/libs/user_libs \
    -e "OPTION_LIBS=ignite-log4j2,ignite-spring,ignite-indexing,ignite-urideploy" \
    -p 47500:47500 \
    -p 47100:47100 \
    apacheignite/ignite:2.14.0
```

After running the docker command, I got the error below

```
[ERROR][grid-uri-scanner-#2-#51][UriDeploymentScannerManager] Runtime error caught during grid runnable execution: IgniteSpiThread [name=grid-uri-scanner-#2-#51]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jna/win32/StdCallLibrary
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_345]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756) ~[?:1.8.0_345]
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[?:1.8.0_345]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:473) ~[?:1.8.0_345]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74) ~[?:1.8.0_345]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369) ~[?:1.8.0_345]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363) ~[?:1.8.0_345]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_345]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[?:1.8.0_345]
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.deployment.uri.GridUriDeploymentClassLoader.loadClass(GridUriDeploymentClassLoader.java:56) ~[ignite-urideploy-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[?:1.8.0_345]
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.deployment.uri.GridUriDeploymentFileResourceLoader.createResource(GridUriDeploymentFileResourceLoader.java:72) ~[ignite-urideploy-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.deployment.uri.GridUriDeploymentDiscovery.findResourcesInDirectory(GridUriDeploymentDiscovery.java:109) ~[ignite-urideploy-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.deployment.uri.GridUriDeploymentDiscovery.findResourcesInDirectory(GridUriDeploymentDiscovery.java:103) ~[ignite-urideploy-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.deployment.uri.GridUriDeploymentDiscovery.findResourcesInDirectory(GridUriDeploymentDiscovery.java:103) ~[ignite-urideploy-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.deployment.uri.GridUriDeploymentDiscovery.findResourcesInDirectory(GridUriDeploymentDiscovery.java:103) ~[ignite-urideploy-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.deployment.uri.GridUriDeploymentDiscovery.getClasses(GridUriDeploymentDiscovery.java:71) ~[ignite-urideploy-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.deployment.uri.GridUriDeploymentFileProcessor.processNoDescriptorFile(GridUriDeploymentFileProcessor.java:388) ~[ignite-urideploy-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.deployment.uri.GridUriDeploymentFileProcessor.processFile(GridUriDeploymentFileProcessor.java:108) ~[ignite-urideploy-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.deployment.uri.UriDeploymentSpi$2.onNewOrUpdatedFile(UriDeploymentSpi.java:587) ~[ignite-urideploy-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.deployment.uri.scanners.file.UriDeploymentFileScanner$URIContext.handleFile(UriDeploymentFileScanner.java:268) ~[ignite-urideploy-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.deployment.uri.scanners.file.UriDeploymentFileScanner$URIContext.access$200(UriDeploymentFileScanner.java:135) ~[ignite-urideploy-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.deployment.uri.scanners.file.UriDeploymentFileScanner$URIContext$1.handle(UriDeploymentFileScanner.java:178) ~[ignite-urideploy-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.deployment.uri.scanners.GridDeploymentFolderScannerHelper.scanFolder(GridDeploymentFolderScannerHelper.java:49) ~[ignite-urideploy-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.deployment.uri.scanners.GridDeploymentFolderScannerHelper.scanFolder(GridDeploymentFolderScannerHelper.java:52) ~[ignite-urideploy-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.deployment.uri.scanners.file.UriDeploymentFileScanner$URIContext.scan(UriDeploymentFileScanner.java:183) ~[ignite-urideploy-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.deployment.uri.scanners.file.UriDeploymentFileScanner$URIContext.access$000(UriDeploymentFileScanner.java:135) ~[ignite-urideploy-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.deployment.uri.scanners.file.UriDeploymentFileScanner.scan(UriDeploymentFileScanner.java:73) ~[ignite-urideploy-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.deployment.uri.scanners.UriDeploymentScannerManager$1.body(UriDeploymentScannerManager.java:115) ~[ignite-urideploy-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:58) [ignite-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387) ~[?:1.8.0_345]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[?:1.8.0_345]
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.deployment.uri.GridUriDeploymentClassLoader.loadClass(GridUriDeploymentClassLoader.java:61) ~[ignite-urideploy-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[?:1.8.0_345]
        ... 30 more
```

I don't quite understand why it throw this error, and how should I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you don't need to deploy `postgresql-42.5.0.jar` using `UriDeploymentSpi` in this particular case since the driver was copied to the `USER_LIBS` and as a result, it's already in the Ignite's classpath and can be used for the [external storage](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/persistence/external-storage#external-storage) configuration.

Anyway, I've filed a ticket for this issue [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-18146).